# What is the word used to describe a person who tends to enthusiastically initiate first action

Tags: single-word-requests

Noticed this single word used in a CV (resume) but forgot to write it down.  It is a single word used to describe a person who enthusiastically initiates action.

Comment: An **initiator**?

Comment: @Helmar The initiator may not enthusiastically initiate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [proactive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proactive) is the word you are searching for.

> (Of a person or action) creating or controlling a situation rather
>   than just responding to it after it has happened